# How to play CineForm RAW files with MPlayer?

Tags: mplayer

The default MPlayer package doesn't allow me to play CineForm RAW files.

Can you suggest me a binary codec that can extend the MPlayer's functionality?

Comment: http://cineform.com/gopro-cineform-decoder

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I meant the MPlayer binary codec.

Comment: Thank you, Tetsujin. It seems work but required some registry hacking. If you'll write your comment as a response I'll mark it as the answer